# How do I allow a salt stack formula to run on only certain operating system versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack

I'm writing a [SaltStack formula](https://github.com/soniah/awsappdiscovery-formula) for installation of [AWS Application Discovery Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/application-discovery/latest/userguide/what-is-appdiscovery.html).

The install script requires certain OS versions - how do I account for that in my formula?

The map.jinja in the [redis formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/redis-formula/blob/master/redis/map.jinja) does the following - is this the correct way?

```
{% set os_map = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'Debian': {
        'pkg_name': 'redis-server',
        'svc_name': 'redis-server',
        'cfg_name': '/etc/redis/redis.conf',
        'cfg_version': salt['grains.filter_by']({
            'wheezy': '2.4',
            'jessie': '2.8',
            'default': '2.8'
}, grain='oscodename'),
```

OS Requirements:

- Ubuntu 14
- Amazon Linux 2012.03 or 2015.03
- Centos 6 or 7
- Redhat 6 or 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping is needed when you have different values on different OSes, take a look at the following example from the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html#abstracting-static-defaults-into-a-lookup-table), map.jinja part in your case you may use the following for example:

```
{% set mysql = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'Debian': {
        'server': 'mysql-server',
        'client': 'mysql-client',
        'service': 'mysql',
        'config': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        'python': 'python-mysqldb',
    },
    'RedHat': {
        'server': 'mysql-server',
        'client': 'mysql',
        'service': 'mysqld',
        'config': '/etc/my.cnf',
        'python': 'MySQL-python',
    },
    'Gentoo': {
        'server': 'dev-db/mysql',
        'client': 'dev-db/mysql',
        'service': 'mysql',
        'config': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        'python': 'dev-python/mysql-python',
    },
}) %}
```

The above code will use the values of `server`, `client`, `service`, etc according to the `OS` they will be running on
Note the I have removed the following `merge=salt['pillar.get']('mysql:lookup')`

Another example when you need to start apache service on Ubuntu named `apache2` and on Centos named `httpd` so you need a lookup table to handle different paths and services name.

I didn't have a chance before to try a formula on a random OS other than OSes defined under map.jinja but i think it will be broken.

In order to prevent the formula from running on Unwanted OS you have to wrap your code between `if statement` for example one of your requirement is CentOS 6 or CentOS 7 so what About CentOS 5? You can do the following:

```
# This will be matched with CentOS/Redhat 6 or higher
{% if grains.os_family == 'RedHat' and grains.osmajorrelease >= '6' %}
# do something
{% endif %}
```

And you can use `elif` to add more conditions, take a look to get more information about [using jinja in states](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#jinja-in-states) And DON'T Forget to check the grains of your minions in order to add conditions in a correct way to make it work as expected.

Comment: If it doesn't work with string comparison use int: `grains.osmajorrelease >= 6`